# Xamarin Incompatible target framework error - can NuGet help me?

Tags: c#, reference, xamarin, nuget, target-framework

I am coding a Xamarin application and I wish to add the MonoDroidToolkit as a project to my current solution. I have done this correctly, and my solution builds.

I now need to add a reference in my application to the MonoDroidToolkit project.

I have selected the "Edit References" option in the References folder. I then browse to the projects tab to select the project. The project is listed there, however I cannot select the project because of this description:

> com.refractored.monodroidtoolkit (incompatible target framework:
>   MonoAndroid, Version=v4.2)

Here is an screenshot of the description:
[image: com.refractored.monodroidtoolkit (incompatible target framework: MonoAndroid, Version=v4.2)]

I have changed the target framework of each project to be the same and also to be automatic, however, no matter what target framework I select, I cannot add the reference because of the above description.

I have done a check on the Mono.Android reference in each of my projects. In my current project, the description is version 4.1 Support and the MonoDroidToolkit is version 4.2 support.

Is this that the problem is? How can I easily update the 4.1 Support reference to be the latest? Can I get NuGet to do this, or is there another way to update all my references?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the same solution an Android project can only reference another project if its target framework is the same version or a lower version.

You can change your project's target framework version by right clicking the project in the Solution window, selecting Options, then selecting Build - General. At the top is the Target Framework for that project. If you change that to Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean) then you should be able to reference the MonoDroidToolkit  project.

The simplest way to use MonoDroidToolkit is to install it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoDroid.Toolkit/).

Comment: This worked TY!

Answer (score 0):

Open Xamarin Studio and click check for updates. This should update your Monodroid Version